# Use a Heat generated fragment?

Tags: wix

I have created a fragment for my entire output like this

```
"%WIX%\bin\heat" dir ..\Output -nologo -suid -srd -sfrag -ag -wx -dr "INSTALLFOLDER" -var var.OutputDir -out ..\FreePIE.Setup\main.wxs
```

How do I use this from my Product.wxs?

The doc is really vague on how to use Heat

**edit:**
Got a bit further, now when I build (Using msbuild)

```
msbuild ..\FreePIE.Setup\FreePIE.Setup.wixproj
```

I get

> Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.OutputDir)'.

**edit: Final solution using Candle and light exes**

```
  <Target Name="Candle">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(InstallerTemp)" Command="&quot;$(WIX)\candle.exe&quot; -dOutputDir=&quot;..\Output&quot; -dVersion=&quot;$(Version)&quot; -dProductName=&quot;FreePIE&quot; $(InstallerTemp)\Main.wxs $(InstallerTemp)\Output.wxs"/>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Light">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(InstallerTemp)" Command="&quot;$(WIX)\light.exe&quot; -ext WixUIExtension -ext WiXNetFxExtension -out FreePIE.$(Version).msi $(InstallerTemp)\Main.wixobj $(InstallerTemp)\Output.wixobj"/>
  </Target>
```

Main.wsx holds the main definition and Output.wxs the heat generated wsx. -dOutputDir= to set the flag

For a full solution see
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/tree/master/BuildTools

The batch that calls all logic is 
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/blob/master/BuildTools/build_installer.bat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do next:

1. Add Preprocessor variable to your project. Project->
   Properties->Build OutputDir=my path
2. Add group name to your command `-cg MyFilesGroup`
3. Add MyFilesGroup to your product feature

   <Feature Id=ProductFeature" Title="$(var.ProductName)" Level="1">

   <ComponentGroupRef Id="MyFilesGroup"/>

   </Feature>

Comment: Thanks, I just did that, got a bit further. I also included the Heat generatged file in my wixproject, is that correct? Anyway, now it cant find the variable  var.OutputDir how can I set it to my output dir?

Comment: @Anders Include that file in project is not required.

Comment: Nice :D about the variable?

Comment: Hmm get Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixComponentGroup:Output' if i remove reference from project

Comment: @Anders Look at my edit. Oh yes you are right it should in project sorry i forgot

Comment: Nice one final question and i will mark as answer, how can I set them through msbuild? /p:OutputDir=..\Output does not work

Comment: @Anders Realy i don't know why /p:OutputDir=value not working for your. I am using there absolute path and its working. For test try absolute path

Comment: @Anders who saying more details please

Comment: I ended up using candle and light exes instead and the the flag -dOutputDir="..\Output"

Comment: I updated the question with my final solution, also linked to the code